# Using pyspark to connect to hive tables

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

I am trying to query a Hive table from pyspark.

I am using the below statements:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext    
HiveContext(sc).sql('from `dbname.tableName` select `*`')
```

I am very new to hadoop systems.
Need to understand what is the correct way to bring some data from a hive table and storing it into a dataframe to further write a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlCtx.sql` has access to hive table. You can use it following way.

```
my_dataframe = sqlCtx.sql("Select * from employees")

my_dataframe.show()
```